# Text appearing outside of set width when echoing a variable

Tags: css

I've created an page where users can view images along with the image description although I'm having some issues with the CSS for the description. The description is retrieved via PHP and is shown as a echoed variable. The issue with this is that the descriptions seems to carry on along one single line when it should be carrying on within the div.

As shown below, it displays along one line when it should be wrapping below to the same width as the text area below the description.

I've tried changing the width of the .desc class to a set pixel width of 290px instead 100% (should still take the 290px from the image-desc class container) but I'm having no luck.

[image: Text screwiness]

My current CSS:

```
 .image-info {
    width: 290px;
    display: inline;
    float: right;
}

.image-info .desc {
    text-align: justify;
    width: 290px;
    margin: 10px 0px;
}
```

and the HTML:

```
<div class="image-info">
        <? $desc = htmlentities($row['desc'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'); ?>
        <a href="gallery.php?id=<?php echo htmlentities($row['gallery'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'); ?>">&larr; Back to Gallery</a>
        <div class="desc"><? echo $desc; ?></div>

        <? if(empty($_SESSION['user'])) { } else { print '<a href="#" class="show_hide"><i class="icon-chevron-down"></i>Options</a><br /><div class="slidingDes"><form action="admin/includes/edit-img.php?id=' . $id . '" method="post">  <textarea type="text" name="description" placeholder="' . $desc . '"></textarea> <br/><input type="submit" value="Change" class="btn btn-primary"/> </form><form action="admin/includes/cover-image.php?id=' . $id . '" method="post">  <input type="submit" value="Cover Photo" class="btn btn-danger"/> </form></div>';}?>
    </div>
```

Comment: plz share your html code to so that we can look into this problem easily

Comment: Added, sorry about that.

Comment: I have posted my answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the new CSS 3 `word-break` property:

```
word-break: break-word; /* Will prevent text from bleeding outside container */
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems that your content go beyond the limit when there is no white space in the word 
so just add `word-wrap:break-word;` to imageInfo class

here is your css

```
 .image-info {
    width: 290px;
    display: inline;
    float: right;
    word-wrap:break-word;
}
```

Take a look here in [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vu5hL/)

Answer (score 0):

Use the CSS3 word wrap

```
word-wrap:break-word;
```

This will force the text to go down